# How to specify PHP Xdebug extension in VSCode?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I have two installed extensions: `xdebug.php-debug` and `devsense.phptools-vscode`. Both support  PHP debugging.

How can I specify which one to use for debugging?

If both are enabled, every debug session is caught by `devsense.phptools-vscode`, but I prefer to use `xdebug.php-debug` for debugging.

If `devsense.phptools-vscode` is disabled, - everything works well, and step-debugging works through `xdebug.php-debug`.

Unfortunately, I need `devsense.phptools-vscode` enabled for other functions.

Is there a way to specify which extension to use for debugging?

Perhaps it's possible to set extension priority or something similar?

Comment: do both extensions implement the same launch config type

Comment: Yes. `"type": "php"` in launch.json